# Inserting string with single quotes from Java into Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, quotes

I'm inserting text from a Java application into a Postgresql database, but it all crashes when a ' char is encountered in the String. I've tried using replaceAll(" ' ", " \\' ");  even diffrent variants of it with more \ chars, yet it still puts a single ' in the String without the escape sign.

Is there any way of replacing the ' with an \' in the String? Or another way of putting Strings containig single quotes into Postgresql?

Comment: I have a similar issue, I am using hibernate queries and when trying to insert if a field contains single quotes, an exception is thrown

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about doing this manually if you're using [prepared statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) properly.

Comment: +1 for prepared statements. Those are really the proper way to do this.

Comment: +1 for prepared statements from me too.  Be careful about exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you, I followed Your advice and changed it to a proper prepared statement, turned out I was using it the wrong way. This also resolved the issue.

Comment: I'd recommend moving the accepted answer to this one. That way other folks will see the correct solution first. Nothing wrong, exactly, with the single quote escaping, but it's not generally a good practice to build SQL strings like that.

Comment: How do i go about solving similar issue when I am using hibernate saveOrUpdate(Object ), query and the issue occurs if one of the String  fields in the Object contain a  single quotes

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809307/how-to-save-s-string-containing-single-quotes-to-column-of-datatype-text-of-a-ta]   is a similar issue which uses hibernate instead of sql,

Answer (score 2):

Most SQL implementations use '' (2 single quotes) to escape a single quote.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE f_name='foo''bar';
```

Or you could use double dollar sign:

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE f_name=$$foo''bar$$;
```

Both statements would search for the string foo'bar

Comment: Yes, this is a feature of standard SQL and PostgreSQL supports this.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: But you still want to use bind variables and prepared statements.

Comment: I would agree that prepared statements are the way to go.  But sometimes legacy code makes you choose your battles.

Comment: I doubt legacy code is an issue here.  PostegreSQL has a JDBC driver.